# Vim & Vimperator: Map Windows/Meta key?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to map the Windows/Meta key in my vimperatorrc & vimrc, including Meta-key bindings for tab movement:

```
" move to previous tab
nnoremap <M-h> gT

" move to next tab
nnoremap <M-l> gt
```

Unfortunately neither Vimperator nor Vim accepts these bindings. Although they do not complain, the bindings simply do not work.

According to this tutorial: [How to map keys in Vim](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_map_keys_in_vim), `<M-...>` should map the meta (windows) key?!

Any ideas?

**System setup:**
I am using [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) and [Vimperator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimperator) on [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro_Linux) ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) Fork) within [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE). Thus, Vim runs in [Yakuake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuake) (KDE's terminal "manager"/"multiplexer") and Vimperator in [FireFox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) 48.

**Sidenote**: Vim shows the same behavior when launched in a normal terminal, outside of Yakuake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim, meta is the same as alt. Cp. `:help meta`:

```
<M-...>     alt-key or meta-key     *meta* *alt* *<M-*
<A-...>     same as <M-...>         *<A-*
```

In Pentadactyl, this supposedly works (cp. `:help key-notation`):

```
<A-␣>: The alt key.
<M-␣>: The meta key, windows key, or command key.
```

But at least for me (on Ubuntu with Gnome classic), meta mappings don't work at all (probably because they don't arrive in the browser at all).